# Proving one sided limit with epsilon-delta and proving limit as $x \rightarrow -\infty$ with epsilon-delta

Tags: real-analysis, epsilon-delta

## Problems

**a**) Find  $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0^+}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0^-}f(x)$ for $f(x) = \frac{x + |x|}{x}$, and $x_0 = 0$

**b**) Show that $\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty}(1-\frac{1}{x^2})=1$

---

## My attempt

**a**)
For the left hand side limit:
$$\forall \epsilon \gt 0 \, \,\exists \, \,\delta \, \,\ \,\text{s.t} \,\,|f(x) - L|<\epsilon  \,\, \text{if} \, \, x_0 - \delta < x < x_0$$
$$ L = 0, x_0 = 0 $$
$$-\delta \lt x \lt 0\, \, ,  |\frac{x+ |x|}{x}| < \epsilon$$

For the right hand side limit:
$$\forall \epsilon \gt 0 \, \,\exists \, \,\delta \, \,\ \,\text{s.t} \,\,|f(x) - L|<\epsilon  \,\, \text{if} \, \, x_0 < x < x_0 + \delta$$
$$L = 2, x_0 = 0$$
$$0 \lt x \lt \delta\, \, ,  |\frac{x+ |x|}{x} -2| < \epsilon$$
$$| \frac{2x}{x}| - 2= 0  \lt \epsilon $$

But how do I find expressions for delta for both the right-handside and left-handside limits?

**b)**
Per definition:
$\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} f(x) = L$ if $f(x)$ is defined on an interval $(-\infty, b)$, and for all $\epsilon \gt 0$ there is $\beta$ such that $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ if $x \lt \beta$.
Then:
$$|f(x) - L| = |1 - \frac{1}{x^2} - 1| = \frac{1}{x^2} \lt \epsilon \Rightarrow x \lt -\sqrt{\frac{1}{\epsilon}} $$
and thus $\beta = -\sqrt{\frac{1}{\epsilon}}$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**a)** Since the function $f(x)$ is constant (in every side separately), so $\delta$ is arbitrary, for simplicity you can assume $\delta = \epsilon$.

**b)** This is correct, only you must add, $b < 0$, restriction.